# How to save Object value in a variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I save that password in a variable so that I can check it with user input and authenticate.

Below is my code.

```
 app.post('/check-user',(req,res)=>{

        var user=req.body.n1;
        var pass=req.body.n2;
        MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true},function(err,db){
        if(err) throw err;
        var dbase = db.db("db");
        //var query = { username: user };
          dbase.collection("users").find({"username":user},{projection:{_id:0,Name:0,username:0}}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            db.close();
            });
        });
})

app.listen(8080,()=>{})
```

output is [{password:'keshav'}]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly,
You should not store actual password in database. Instead you should use a module like [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) to encrypt your password and then store it. You should google for it. There are tons of articles/tutorials about authentication in NodeJS.

About checking password, you are using this line to store user's given password in the pass variable (`var pass=req.body.n2;`), right? So, I believe a simple comparison operator should work in your case. Example:

```
if (result[0].password === pass) {
  console.log('Loggedin');
} else {
  console.log('Login failed');
}
```